# Salesforce - converting leads in opportunities, error message

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have problems converting my leads in Opportunities on Salesforce. Whenever I convert a saved lead, I get the following error message below the field: "Converted Status: Qualified".

> Error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for
>   restricted picklist field: 1. first contact: [Partnership_Level__c]
>   Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.handleRegularAccountInserts: line
>   226, column 1 Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.convertLead: line 88,
>   column 1

Can anyone help?

Best,
Nicholas

Answer (score 1):

You need to check values of Picklist fields which your code populate, seems you are just trying to assign value to field, which is not included in list of available values. Try to use debug logs for getting more info.

Also, on picklist fields exists such option as 'Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set', you can try to uncheck it for avoiding mentioned issue.